# Excel VBA opening file with the latest version

Tags: excel, vba

just starting to learn VBA for excel and experimenting in automating my routine work. 
I have a workbook which some of the contents are copied from other files. In the same file directory, i have several files that data i copied with. The problem is the files have several versioning, for example:

- companyA_20151101.xlx
- companyA_20151105.xlx
- companyA_20151106.xlx
- companyB_20151105.xlx
- companyC_20151109.xlx

I take documents from company A to C, but having problem due to the date. Would it be possible to tell VBA just pick the latest version (i.e. for companyA takes the one with 06 date)?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a UDF to return a string with the correct file name. I've assumed from the naming convention that the most recent file is actually *created* on that date and therefore will have the most recent Creation Date property.

```
Function GetRecentFile(partialFileName As String) As String

Dim files As Variant
Dim checkDate As Date
Dim returnFile As String

With CreateObject("System.FileScriptingObject")

    files = Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & partialFileName & _
        "*.xl*"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")

    checkDate = .GetFile(CStr(files(0))).DateCreated

    For Each file In files
        If .GetFile(CStr(file)).DateCreated > checkDate Then
            checkDate = .GetFile(CStr(file)).DateCreated
            returnFile = CStr(file)
        End If
    Next

End With

GetRecentFile = returnFile

End Function
```

Use like so:

```
Sub MM()

Dim myFile As String, wb As Excel.Workbook

myFile = GetRecentFile("C:\Users\MM\Work Files\CompanyA")

If Not myFile = vbNullString Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myFile)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That is very creative approach, i didn't know vba can distinguish creation date...very insightful for a newbie like me.

Answer (score 0):

I've approached this slightly differently and am using the date suffix on the filename to determine which is the 'latest' file:

```
Public Function MostRecentCompanyFile(ByRef strCompany As String, _
                                    ByRef strDirectory As String) As String

Dim strDir          As String
Dim datDateSuffix   As Date
Dim strLatest       As String
Dim datLatest       As Date

strDir = Dir(strDirectory & "\" & strCompany & "*")

Do Until Len(strDir) = 0
    datDateSuffix = StripDate(strDir)

    If Len(strLatest) = 0 Then
        'the first iteration
        strLatest = strDir
        datLatest = datDateSuffix
    ElseIf datDateSuffix > datLatest Then
        'this file has a later date suffix so this is now the latest
        strLatest = strDir
        datLatest = datDateSuffix
    End If
    'get the next file
    strDir = Dir
Loop

MostRecentCompanyFile = strLatest

End Function

Private Function StripDate(ByRef strFileName As String) As Date

Dim intPos  As Integer
Dim strDate As String
Dim datDate As Date

'assume the date suffix occurs after the underscore in the file name and is in the format yyyymmdd
intPos = InStr(1, strFileName, "_")

strDate = Mid$(strFileName, intPos + 1, 8)

datDate = DateSerial(Left$(strDate, 4), Mid$(strDate, 5, 2), Right$(strDate, 2))

StripDate = datDate

End Function
```

Here, we are:

1. Looping through all the files in the given `strDirectory`.
2. Stripping off the date suffix (using the `StripDate` method).
3. Comparing this date to all others for the given `strCompany`.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I don't understand some of those codes (yet) but i assume i have to put a check first to anticipate if the users does not use the appropriate filenaming conventions (e.g •companyA_20151101 v2revised.xlxs)?

Comment: @dedhie correct, yes. This code is making the assumption that the filenames are in a convention like: `strCompany_YYYYMMDD` where `strCompany` can be any string.